# Отступ в v-layout

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Как в `v-layout` (vietify) задать вертикальный отступ между строками?

```
    <v-layout
        row
        style="margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 4%; display: flex; justify-content: start"
        v-show="!loading"
    >
        <div
            class="custom-app-containers display-1"
            style="padding-left: 7px"
        >
            <b>{{ title }}</b>
        </div>
        <div
            v-for="course in courses"
            :key="course.id"
        >
            <Card
                style="margin: 0; padding: 0"
                :course="course"
            />
        </div>
    </v-layout>
```

[image: ue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается очень просто. Избавляемся от `<v-layout>` и задаём `flex-wrap: wrap`

```
<div
    style="margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 4%; display: flex; justify-content: start; flex-wrap: wrap; "
    v-show="!loading"
>
    <div
        class="custom-app-containers display-1"
        style="padding-left: 7px"
    >
        <b>{{ title }}</b>
    </div>
    <div
        v-for="course in courses"
        :key="course.id"
    >
        <Card
            style="margin: 0; padding: 0"
            :course="course"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]